# do you know any example which is not lattice norm?

Tags: vector-lattices

A norm $||.||$ on a Riesz space is said to be lattice norm whenever $|x|\leq |y|$ implies $||x||\leq ||y||$. Do you know any example which is not a lattice norm?

Comment: Where is this definition of lattice norm from? What is your source for this? Also is $|x| := (x) \vee (-x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Take the Sobolev space $H^1(0,1)$. For example, you could choose $y \equiv 1$ and $x(t) = \sin(n \, t)$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Hi, do you know a good source for where this idea of lattice norm is defined. Also is $|x| := (x) \vee (-x)$? Thanks.

Comment: You can find it, e.g., in Schaefer's "Banach Lattices and Positive Operators", p.5, (8).